# Dialog Pop Up with Contents(info) and Buttons

Tags: java, swing

I wish to create a dialog Pop Up Box where the details of an Item ,the image next to it and a "Yes" or "No" Button Options below them. Specifically, I am trying to show the details of a DVD and ask the user if he wishes to rent it.

Here's the picture if that helps(sorry I couldn't find an image online):
[image]

Then I wish to create an additional pop up promting the user for information if he chooses the "Yes" option.

My question is how to create this? I didn't find any answers in the JOptionPane documentation and tutorials.

Comment: How far did you get?

Comment: @ Armand I've found out how to present the details,but not in a popup with the picture. Here's the code :

if (e.getSource() == but3) {
   int i = list.getSelectedIndex();
   String outputText = products_list.get(i).getContents();
   resultArea.setText(outputText);
     }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a JOptionPane (as you said.)

Basically, you want to have `JOptionPane` create a dialog for you. For a yes-or-no question, you would use a confirm dialog. So you would start with this:

```
int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
    contents, "dialog-title", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Now, to explain the code:

The first argument is the frame that the dialog will show up on. I'm assuming you're calling this from an existing frame's code, so I put `this` there.

Next, you'll see a variable called `contents`. It can be any object, but here you want it to be a `JPanel`. Basically, you create a single panel containing everything you want above the buttons and pass it in as the message. This will put that panel above the two buttons (which JOptionPane will create for you).

The next argument is just the title of the dialog.

`YES_NO_OPTION` gives you the "yes" and "no" buttons instead of "ok" and "cancel".

I used PLAIN_MESSAGE because that doesn't put an icon on the dialog.

Finally, there is a return value, which I stored in `choice`. It will be equal to either `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION`, `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION`, or `JOptionPane.CLOSE_OPTION`. From there, if the user clicks "yes", you can make the next dialog show up and create it in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you implying that I will make a JPanel where the info will be presented, as well as the image? Or do I need to make two JPanels? Can you clarify on that please?

Comment: @MariosAth You want to create a single JPanel containing everything above the two buttons.